# constante de linkeado de paginas en mi navbar PHP no funciona

Tags: php, vistas, enlace, constantes, configuración

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas tardes es que quiero poner una constante para el head de mis views pero no me quiere funcionar, el resto si. Es al momento de darle al botón de nosotros de mi navbar, según entiendo las constantes se pueden utilizar de esta manera para que los links funcionen independientemente del lugar donde se encuentre la vista. Les agradezco

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta y pon el código como texto, no como imagen. También incluye la declaración de la constante.

Comment: <li><a href="<?php echo VIEWS_HOME.'news.php' ?>">NOSOTROS</a></li>

Comment: // Constantes de los paths de archivos
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); // = \
define('ROOT', getcwd().DS);  //obtiene la direccion del disco
define('PROVIDERS', ROOT.'providers'.DS);  //obtiene la direccion del disco
define('VIEWS', ROOT.'views'.DS);
define('VIEWS_HOME',ROOT.'views'.DS.'home'.DS.'solumobil'.DS);